# How to insert string at index in TMemoryStream?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How can I insert a string at a specified index in `TMemoryStream`? If you added a string 
"a" to an existing string "b" at Index 0 it would move it forward "ab" etc. For example this is what `TStringBuilder.Insert` does.

Answer (score 3):

1. Expand the stream so that there is room for the text to be inserted. So, if the text to be inserted has length `N`, then you need to make the stream `N` bytes larger.
2. Copy all the existing content, starting from the insertion point, to the right to make room for the insertion. A call to `Move` will get this done. You'll be moving this text `N` bytes to the right.
3. Write the inserted string at the insertion point.

I'm assuming an 8 bit encoding. If you use a 16 bit encoding, then the stream needs to be grown by `2N` bytes, and so on.

You will find that this is a potentially expensive operation. If you care about performance you will do whatever you can to avoid ever having to do this.

P.S. I'm sorry if I have offended any right-to-left language readers with my Anglo-centric assumption that strings run from left to right!

---

You asked for some code. Here it is:

```
procedure TMyStringBuilder.Insert(Index: Integer; const Str: string);
var
  N: Integer;
  P: Char;
begin
  N := Length(Str);
  if N=0 then
    exit;
  FStream.Size := FStream.Size + N*SizeOf(Char);
  P := PChar(FStream.Memory);      
  Move((P + Index)^, (P + Index + N)^, (FStream.Size - N - Index)*SizeOf(Char));
  Move(Pointer(Str)^, (P + Index)^, N*SizeOf(Char));
end;
```

Note that I wrote this code, and then looked at the code in `TStringBuilder`. It's pretty much identical to that!

---

The fact that the code you end up writing for this operation is identical to that in `TStringBuilder` should cause you to stop and contemplate. It's very likely that this new string builder replacement class that you are building will end up with the same implementation as the original. It's highly likely that your replacement will perform no better than the original, and quite plausible that the performance of the replacement will be worse.

It looks a little to me as though you are optimising prematurely. According to your comments below you have not yet timed your code to prove that time spent in `TStringBuilder` methods is your bottleneck. That's really the first thing that you need to do.

Assuming that you do this timing, and prove that `TStringBuilder` methods are your bottleneck, you then need to identify why that code is performing below par. And then you need to work out how the code could be improved. Simply repeating the implementation of the original class is not going to yield any benefits.

Comment: @Eric No it would not.

Comment: I believe that in RTL communities string only goes right-to-left on 2D screens. Same for top-to-bottom languages and the rest. In memory there is no left, right, up, down, north, west, etc. There is either address1 > address2 or address2 > address1. Interpreting those comparisons as "left" or "right" is delusion that there is some "proper" mapping of linear memory to 2D space. There is not. I saw books that used all 4 directions or mix of those :-)

Comment: @EricSantos - You mean that copying data 3 times (memory string -> string, strings concatenation, string -> memory stream) is faster than copying data one time (memory stream concatenation) ? I have doubts

Comment: What you will discover at the end of this exercise is that you have rebuilt `TStringBuilder`. Why do you think your version will be faster. And I wonder why you needed me to write this code when you have the `TStringBuilder` code in front of you.

Comment: I've got a question for you. What proportion of the time does your application spend executing `TStringBuilder.Insert` or `TStringBuilder.Append`?

Comment: My code is for 8 bit text. You'll need to adapt it for 16 bit text. Add a `*SizeOf(Char)` to the `Size := ` line, and the two `Move` commands.

Comment: Now, I am astounded that you are writing this code before benchmarking. What if your program spends very little time in the string builder?!

Comment: You need to scale Index too

Comment: If you write the same code as TStringBuilder why do you think it will be faster? And I don't think I forgot anything. After all, it's your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not really mine. Embarcadero's.

Comment: Perhaps you should just write you own string builder, or use the Delphi one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Or perhaps you should test the code you post.

Comment: Why should I? Surely that's your job. What do I owe you? Anyway, that code that I posted is correct. But it's for 8 bit text. It's easy enough to convert to 16 bit code. I'm sure you can manage it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And why wouldnt it not be needed?

Comment: Why would it be needed? Your code is all wrong.
The size of a character is not determined by whether or not the insertion index is 0. It seems to me that you don't really want my help. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then please remove this answer so I can remove this question.

Comment: Why? I answered the question. I do actually know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful. The width of a character is 1 byte if you insert it an index 0, but the width is 2 bytes if you insert it elsewhere. You need help but are not able to accept it. Let me help you.

Comment: Your next step is to time your program. Smart money says that string builder is not the bottleneck. In which case you can move on. Optimising the code that does not run is pointless. I know about this. My program is all about perf.

Comment: What a complete waste of time. Time to close SO account.

Comment: The waste of time is your premature optimisation. You note that TStringBuilder has issues and then simply re-create a broken version of it.

Comment: I know you were struggling to convert my original code to work with 16 bit text. The code in the answer does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

To move the existing data to make some room for the new string data, you can use pointer operation and `Move` procedure for faster operation. But it only has to be done if the insertion index is lower then the size of the original stream. If the index is larger than stream size then you could: (1) expand the stream size to accomodate the index number and fill the extra room with zero values or spaces, or (2) reduce the index value to the stream size, so the string will be inserted or appended in the end of the stream.

Depend on your needs, you could: (1) make a class derived from TMemoryStream, or (2) make a function to process an instance of TMemoryStream. Here's the first case:

```
type
  TExtMemoryStream = class(TMemoryStream)
  public
    procedure InsertString(Index: Integer; const S: string);
  end;

procedure TExtMemoryStream.InsertString(Index: Integer; const S: string);
var
  SLength, OldSize: Integer;
  Src, Dst, PointerToS: ^Char;
begin
  if Index > Size then Index := Size;
  SLength := Length(S);
  OldSize := Size;
  SetSize(Size + SLength);
  Src := Memory; Inc(Src, Index);
  Dst := Src; Inc(Dst, SLength);
  Move(Src^, Dst^, OldSize - Index);
  PointerToS := @S[1];
  Move(PointerToS^, Src^, SLength);
end;
```

or the second case:

```
procedure InsertStringToMemoryStream(MS: TMemoryStream;
  Index: Integer; const S: string);
var
  SLength, OldSize: Integer;
  Src, Dst, PointerToS: ^Char;
begin
  if Index > MS.Size then Index := MS.Size;
  SLength := Length(S);
  OldSize := MS.Size;
  MS.SetSize(MS.Size + SLength);
  Src := MS.Memory; Inc(Src, Index);
  Dst := Src; Inc(Dst, SLength);
  Move(Src^, Dst^, OldSize - Index);
  PointerToS := @S[1];
  Move(PointerToS^, Src^, SLength);
end;
```

There, hope it helps :)

Comment: SizeOf(Char)=2. Interesting names here. Passing Src to the Dest param is a bit odd. The if is simply needless. You can just remove the if and do the move all the time.

Comment: Well, if Index = OldSize, it will move zero (OldSize - Index) data, it is pointless.

Comment: Indeed, so simplify the code by removing the if. Move will perform the same check. Pointless write the check twice.